# PyQt:Why a popup dialog prevents execution of other code?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qdialog

I am having a little problem with a pop up dialog.I have a combobox,which when the option changes it pops up a dialog with a textedit widget,do some stuff and insert some text in the textedit widget.

This is what i use for the popup:

```
def function_1(self):
    dialog = QDialog()
    dialog.ui = Ui_Dialog_popup()
    dialog.ui.setupUi(dialog)
    dialog.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
    dialog.exec_()
```

I have the pop up gui code made in QtDesignere in a separate py file.

The popup dialog appears,but if the dialog is not closed,nothing else can be executed.Do you know how can I deal with this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

That's exactly what the `exec` method of [`QDialog`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qdialog.html) is designed for: modal dialogs. Read the "Modal" and "Modeless dialog" sections.

If you don't the dialog to block your main UI, call `show()` instead of `exec()` (and check the [`modal`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qdialog.html#modal-prop) property documentation).

Comment: So with modal you cant interact with the main application and with modeless you can.I replaced exec() with show() but the popup appears and disappears in seconds,what else do i need to change ? Thanks.

Comment: You need that object to stay alive as long as you need it. It probably needs to be a member of your class. I'm guessing it's getting destroyed when the function returns in your code (but I'm not very familiar with python).

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on what Mat said: The show() function immediately returns, and as dialog is local to this function, the object gets deleted as soon as "function_1" returns. You might want to make the dialog a member or global (whichever suits your requirement) so that the object stays in memory.

HTH

Comment: I went with the global option and it worked.One problem is that the dialog's windows appear,then the next function connected to the combobox executes and then the widgets inside the popup dialog appear.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're setting the `WA_DeleteOnClose` window attribute, I'm assuming you want to create a new dialog every time the `function_1` method is called (which is probably a good idea).

If so, the simplest way to solve your issue (based on the code you've given), is to give your dialog a parent (so it is kept alive), and then display it [modelessly](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qdialog.html#modeless-dialogs) using `show()`:

```
def function_1(self):
    dialog = QDialog(self)
    dialog.ui = Ui_Dialog_popup()
    dialog.ui.setupUi(dialog)
    dialog.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
    dialog.show()
```